# Search strings in multiple files/processes/modules (x64dbg)

Tags: x64dbg

when you click `String references` in x64dbg, it only lists strings from current module/file. Is that possible to search strings in multiple (selected) files/modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I know you can search for `String references` in all modules.
The way is: right click ---> search for ---> all modules ---> String references
[image]
[image]